# Cannot auto-complete generic fields in Chromium when 1Password is enabled

Tags: browser, chromium, autocomplete, 1password

I'm having this problem in forms not related with login, sign-up, buy, shipping...

For example, we have a ticket system based on Trac. When I have 1Password set as default password manager in MS Edge Chromium, it doesn't show the autocompletion

[image]

Now, if I either disable the extension or uncheck the "Make 1Password the default password manager", then the autocompletion works correctly:

[image]

While it doesn't affect the webpage functionality it is a negative point in productivity, specially when filling forms containing (like here) usernames or other DB-key-like data (in my case at least).

This happens in other Chromium-based browsers too, like Chrome, but it works correctly in Firefox (1Password completes passwords and other contact info, but generic fields are handled by the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this very same question to 1Password Support Team and they very gently solved my problem. As it is not documented anywhere else I'm publishing the solution here.

---

What you want is to have both 1Password X and the browser autofilling enabled simultaneously. While it may cause some side effects, if you know when 1Password shows up and when the browser does, you might just be able to use them both without getting confused and performing wrong actions. By default, 1Password X disables the browser's built-in autofilling to prevent such confusion for users, but it seems you might benefit from having both turned on.

Please try this:

- Enable 1Password in your browser.
- Right click the 1Password icon on the top right corner and select `Settings`.
- Under the `General` section in the settings page, turn off `Make 1Password the default password manager`.
  [image]
- Open your browser and type `chrome://settings` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll reach your browser settings.
- Type `fill` in the search bar at the top of the page, select `Passwords`, and turn off the "Offer to save passwords" option.
  [image]
- Go back to the `fill` search results, select `Payment info` and disable that feature as well.
  [image]
- Go back to the `fill` search results, select `Personal info` and make sure it is turned on. This is the feature that suggests autofilling random fields like the one you showed in your screenshot.
  [image]

Now you'll have 1Password for autofilling passwords and credit cards, and you'll have browser's built-in autofilling for addresses and other fields.